# How to set response of an api on submit using redux in react js.?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, redux

I'm trying to send an response to the api on submit but the problem I'm having is that when ever i hit submit button my `paymentMethod` parameter is somehow not going through in the api. below I'm posting my submit button and my action. other than that I'm also getting this error.[image: error]

submit

```
 submitPaypal = () => {
    const { frequencyPaypal, paymentMethod } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      paymentMethod: "Paypal",
    });
    this.props.setPaymentOption({
      frequencyPaypal,
      paymentMethod,
    });
  };
```

Action/payment.js

```
export const setPaymentOption = (userdata) => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(fullScreenLoader(true));
    let token = await getToken();
    const api = new Axios();
    const response = await api.post(
      SET_PAYMENT_OPTION,
      {
        paymentOption: userdata.paymentOption,
        paypalPaymentOption: userdata.paypalPaymentOption,
        trustlyPaymentOption: userdata.trustlyPaymentOption,
        payoutReferenceId: userdata.payoutReferenceId,
        varation_id: userdata.varation_id,
      },
      {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      API_URL2
    );
    const { data } = response;
    console.log(userdata)
    dispatch(fullScreenLoader(false));
    dispatch({
      type: SET_PAYMENT,
      payload: data,
    });
  };
};
```

reducer

```
case SET_PAYMENT:
        return {
          ...state,
          paymentGateway: action.payload,
        };
```

map state to props

```
const mapStateToProps = (data) => ({
  webSercvices: data.payments.webServices,
  paymentGate: data.payments.paymentGateway,
  payByPaypal: data.payments.payByPaypal,
  user: data.authenticateUser.user,
  isAuthenticated: data.authUser,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      getPaymentWebServiceApi,
      alertPopUp,
      setPaymentOption,
      savePaypal,
      authenticateUser,
    },
    dispatch
  );
```

Comment: `paymentMethod` or `paymentOption`? The error in the image implies the latter, but you send the former to `setPaymentOption`.

Comment: How did you map dispatch to props for setPaymentOption?

Comment: @HMR i have updated my code added map state to props

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUE**

on `submit` you are sending `frequencyPaypal` and `paymentMethod` in `setPaymentOption` action and there you are accessing many properties which is undefined there like `paymentOption` and more...

**SUGGESTION**

In (Action/payment.js)

```
const response = await api.post(
      SET_PAYMENT_OPTION,
      {
        paymentOption: userdata.paymentOption, // this is undefined
        paymentOption: userdata.frequencyPaypal, // this is valid
        paymentOption: userdata.paymentMethod, // this is valid


        paypalPaymentOption: userdata.paypalPaymentOption, // this is undefined
        trustlyPaymentOption: userdata.trustlyPaymentOption, // this is undefined
        payoutReferenceId: userdata.payoutReferenceId, // this is undefined
        varation_id: userdata.varation_id, // this is undefined
      },
      {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      API_URL2
);
```

Comment: what should i do to replace it?

Comment: @AbdulRaufKhalid you should remove the values which are undefined, or you can send those values to action so it won't be undefined there